# Is it possible to replace percentages with a phrase in a column?

Tags: python, pandas, percentage

I have a table that I am turning into a graph, so I am making it so that the percentages are just whole numbers. For example: `63.9` would be `64%`. I have some percentages that are `less than 1%`, and I would prefer to not have them read `0%`, and rather write, `"less than 1%"` or something like that. Is this possible? Below I wrote a line of code I tried, which runs, but I received a SettingWithCopyWarning, so there are no reflected changes.

```
national_df.loc[national_df['percent']==0.152416, 'percent']='less than 1%'
```

Comment: why `63.9` -> `70%`?

Comment: @I'mahdi oops that was a typo. thanks for catching that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). If `round() == 0` insert `'less than 1%'`.

```
import pandas as pd

# example df
df = pd.DataFrame({'percent' : [0.152416, 1.152416, 10.152416, 63.9]})

# python < 3.8
df['percent'] = df['percent'].apply(lambda x: 'less than 1%' if round(x) == 0 else f'{round(x)}%')

# python >= 3.8
# df['percent'] = df['percent'].apply(lambda x: 'less than 1%' if (res:=round(x)) == 0 else f'{res}%')
print(df)
```

---

```
        percent
0  less than 1%
1            1%
2           10%
3           64%
```